# How to fetch data from two columns of same table without using union?

Tags: php, select, mysqli, tree, union

**I have some piece of code in which i am fetching data of same table via using Union but now i want to do without union**

```
    select leftn as SId , TId
from test_tree
inner join (select @sid:=(select group_concat(leftn,',',rightn)
                          from test_tree
                          where find_in_set(sid, @nsid))
                 , @nsid:=@sid as fset
            from test_tree, (select @nsid:='AMSJUTATE',@sid='')v )gr
        on find_in_set(leftn,fset) where leftn <> ''
union
(select rightn as SId , TId
from test_tree
inner join (select @sid:=(select group_concat(leftn,',',rightn) 
                          from test_tree
                          where find_in_set(sid, @nsid))
                 , @nsid:=@sid as fset
            from test_tree, (select @nsid:='AMSJUTATE',@sid='')v )gr
        on find_in_set(rightn,fset) where rightn <> ''
```

Result is shown as

```
    SId     TId
AMSNUDUCU   2
AMSGUWUDE   3
AMSXAWUXU   4
AMSZUCIVO   5
AMSFASOJA   6
AMSTEMUJI   7
AMSBIZEZO   8
AMSXUDINE   9
AMSZEVUTA   10
AMSREXEGI   11
AMSBIXIBO   12
AMSHEFOVI   13
```

and so on

I have a table like this :

SELECT * FROM `test_tree`

```
TId SId         LeftN      RightN     LStatus RStatus   
1     -         AMSJUTATE               1       
2   AMSJUTATE   AMSNUDUCU   AMSFEZAVU   1   1   
3   AMSNUDUCU   AMSGUWUDE   AMSTUTUNE   1   1   
4   AMSFEZAVU   AMSXAWUXU   AMSHALURA   1   1   
5   AMSGUWUDE   AMSZUCIVO   AMSKEFOFA   1   1   
6   AMSTUTUNE   AMSFASOJA   AMSZAPUPE   1   1   
7   AMSXAWUXU   AMSTEMUJI   AMSPOROBE   1   1   
8   AMSHALURA   AMSBIZEZO   AMSFOHOFI   1   1   
9   AMSZUCIVO   AMSXUDINE               1       
10  AMSKEFOFA   AMSZEVUTA               1       
11  AMSFASOJA   AMSREXEGI               1       
12  AMSZAPUPE   AMSBIXIBO               1       
13  AMSTEMUJI   AMSHEFOVI               1       
14  AMSPOROBE   AMSLUPAKE               1       
15  AMSBIZEZO   AMSCUSIPU               1       
16  AMSFOHOFI   AMSCEMUSU               1       
17  AMSXUDINE   AMSKATOTU               1       
18  AMSZEVUTA   AMSLECEVU               1       
19  AMSREXEGI              AMSKOVUSA        1   
20  AMSBIXIBO              AMSLIWULO        1   
21  AMSHEFOVI              AMSJOLOWE        1   
22  AMSLUPAKE              AMSREROXE        1   
23  AMSCUSIPU              AMSPOMUBE        1   
24  AMSCEMUSU              AMSPULINU        1   
25  AMSPULINU              AMSWOFIVO        1
```

and so on.
This query means a parent has left child & right child and i find all child nodes of a single parent via Union but I want to do it in another way , Is there any alternative of my Union query. So please experts help me and modify my query in your expertise styles.

Comment: you can join table with itself . you can search how to self join a table

Comment: I am newbie developer can you please make my query using self join, thanks for seeing and replying on my question