# convert union query to self join

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, self-join

I'm trying to convert this query to one using `self join`.

```
SELECT leftn AS SId,
       TId
FROM test_tree
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT @sid:=
     (SELECT group_concat(leftn, ',', rightn)
      FROM test_tree
      WHERE find_in_set(sid, @nsid)) , @nsid:=@sid AS fset
   FROM test_tree,

     (SELECT @nsid:='AMSJUTATE',@sid='')v)gr ON find_in_set(leftn, fset)
WHERE leftn <> ''
UNION (
SELECT rightn AS SId,
       TId
FROM test_tree
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT @sid:=
     (SELECT group_concat(leftn, ',', rightn)
      FROM test_tree
      WHERE find_in_set(sid, @nsid)) , @nsid:=@sid AS fset
   FROM test_tree,

     (SELECT @nsid:='AMSJUTATE',@sid='')v)gr ON find_in_set(rightn, fset)
WHERE rightn <> ''
```

This query means a parent has left child & right child and I find all child nodes of a single parent via Union but I want to do it in another way. Can someone convert this query self join? I don't know how to convert this query.

Here's an example of the data I'm working with:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tree`

TId SId         LeftN      RightN     LStatus RStatus   
1     -         AMSJUTATE               1       
2   AMSJUTATE   AMSNUDUCU   AMSFEZAVU   1   1   
3   AMSNUDUCU   AMSGUWUDE   AMSTUTUNE   1   1   
4   AMSFEZAVU   AMSXAWUXU   AMSHALURA   1   1   
5   AMSGUWUDE   AMSZUCIVO   AMSKEFOFA   1   1   
6   AMSTUTUNE   AMSFASOJA   AMSZAPUPE   1   1   
7   AMSXAWUXU   AMSTEMUJI   AMSPOROBE   1   1   
8   AMSHALURA   AMSBIZEZO   AMSFOHOFI   1   1   
9   AMSZUCIVO   AMSXUDINE               1       
10  AMSKEFOFA   AMSZEVUTA               1       
11  AMSFASOJA   AMSREXEGI               1       
12  AMSZAPUPE   AMSBIXIBO               1       
13  AMSTEMUJI   AMSHEFOVI               1       
14  AMSPOROBE   AMSLUPAKE               1       
15  AMSBIZEZO   AMSCUSIPU               1       
16  AMSFOHOFI   AMSCEMUSU               1       
17  AMSXUDINE   AMSKATOTU               1       
18  AMSZEVUTA   AMSLECEVU               1       
19  AMSREXEGI              AMSKOVUSA        1   
20  AMSBIXIBO              AMSLIWULO        1   
21  AMSHEFOVI              AMSJOLOWE        1   
22  AMSLUPAKE              AMSREROXE        1   
23  AMSCUSIPU              AMSPOMUBE        1   
24  AMSCEMUSU              AMSPULINU        1   
25  AMSPULINU              AMSWOFIVO        1
```

Comment: Please use all caps for mysql keywords.  Please provide a sqlfiddle with sample data and your desired output.

Comment: i have produce all the data in this question see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159328/how-to-fetch-data-from-two-columns-of-same-table-without-using-union?noredirect=1#comment95148801_54159328

Comment: @amritJha Your question should be able to independent on its own without links. Please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: format SQL query

Comment: I don't understand how format sql query... Can you please elaborate

Comment: @TrebuchetMS  the link which i provided thats also my question please check and reply

Comment: Can anyone answer or help on this question